# error when creating an instance of a class from an include

Tags: php, namespaces, include

Sorry if this is a repost.  I've been reading answers to this same question for an hour but none of the answers are really helping.

I have a file that looks like such.

```
<?php
namespace GA\Db;

require '/Users/brickman/work/r2s/library/GA/Db/Base.php';

if ( ! class_exists('Base')) 
    die('There is no hope!');
```

-- old question
I've checked my directory by following finder and read it with a text editor from the finder, and it is most definitely the file i am looking for.  I also know that i'm accessing the file because i get a file not found error if i put a path that doesn't exist.

The entire file exists to define the class Base.

But when i check if the class exists and thus if i can create an instance of it, it tell me it doesn't exist.

What gives?

-- update

it's working now.  It had to do with how i was referencing the class.  It wanted this:

```
<?php
namespace GA\Db;

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require '/Users/brickman/work/r2s/library/GA/Db/Base.php';

$test = new Base;
```

Now I'm getting errors about a missing class in my include file, but that's unrelated.  Thank you

Comment: Change `include()` to `require()` to force a fatal error, and ensure you have at the top of  your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. Always when developing/testing code, ensure PHP is showing errors on screen.

Comment: And also post some context from the `Base.php` file. Does it have the same `namespace` as the file you're attempting to include it into?

Comment: i just added a namespace to my file(copy/pasted), and now they share the same namespace.

Comment: I also changed include to require and put that line at the top of my script.  Big thanks for that, it's good to see the extra errors.  But it's not erring right now, it just echoes 'there is no hope!'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aliasing to import namespaced classes, take care that class_exists will not work using the short, aliased class name - apparently whenever a class name is used as string, only the full-namespace version can be used

```
use a\namespaced\classname as coolclass;

class_exists( 'coolclass' ) => false
```

Comment: i just edited my code to reflect the new changes in the file.  I'm not using any aliases, and it is not running.  I'll try playing around with aliases.